# Javascript mobile navigation menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I am following an online Lynda.com tutorial where I am formatting a mobile navigation menu via Javascript and JQuery. The first step was downloading JQuery, hooking JQuery and Javascript into my HTML and checking the document with an alert, which worked, but then I needed to type out code below....I have checked it numerous times and cannot see any errors, but the function is not working. Can anyone else see any errors in the code? Thank you.

/* JavaScript Document */

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('nav a.mobile_menu').on('click',function(){

        var currentNavHeight = $('nav').height(); 

        if( currentNavHeight < 5  ){  

                var newNavHeight = $('nav > ul').height() + 15;
                $('nav').animate({'height':newNavHeight+'px'},750);

        }else{

            $('nav').animate({'height':'0px'},750,function(){
                $(this).removeAttr('style');
            });
        }
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){

        if( $(this).width() > 625 ){
            $('nav').removeAttr('style');

        }
});
```

Comment: Can you do it with a jsfiddle?

Comment: Ok I will try, thank you for advice.

Comment: What does your developer's console say?

Comment: Don't use a Fiddle, when you can insert a code snippet right here.

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML and CSS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your provided code sample is incomplete, you do not have the closing brackets for your `$(window).resize` function or for your wrapping `$(document).ready` function.